# how to join first letter of a word with remaining letters of a word?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, split

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of the word, and replace it with smaller first letter of the word.
I am done till, capitalizing the first letter but I do not know how to join the
first letter with the rest of the letter in the word.

```js
let a="i am using stack overflow and it is great";
function makeCapital(){
  const words=a.split(" ");
  console.log(words);
  const firstLetter = words.map(letter=>letter.charAt(0));
  console.log(firstLetter);
  const capitalLetter=firstLetter.map(capital=>capital.toUpperCase());
  console.log(capitalLetter);
}
//I do not know how to join this capiltal letter with rest of the letters in a word
makeCapital();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things here a bit. You can just loop through every word in the sentence (your `words` array here) and uppercase each of them, then join them back:

```
const capitalizedWords = words.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUppercase() + word.slice(1)));
const capitalizedSentence = capitalizedWords.join(" ");
```

`slice` method resturns a portion of an array, given a start and an end(optional) index.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you want to capitalize all the words in the string, so this could help:

```
"I don't know".split(" ").map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(" ")
# => I Don't Know
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join() on a array of string to "glue it back" to a string

So, if you need to capitalize the first letter of each word, you can do this :

```
const str = "i am using stack overflow and it is great";
const res = str
  .split(" ")
  .map((w) => {  return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substring(1); })
  .join(" ");

console.log(res); // I Am Using Stack Overflow And It Is Great
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to capitalize each word of your sentence and want to have something like:

**"I Am Using Stack Overflow And It Is Great"**

You can achieve it with following code:

```
makeCapital = (words) =>
  words.split(" ").map(element =>
    element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.substring(1).toLowerCase()
).join(" ");

makeCapital("i am using stack overflow and it is great");
```

*Reference: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-array*

Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS solution**

If you wish to apply capitals to each word in a sentence for display purposes, it is easily (and arguably better) achieved  with css using `text-transform: capitalize;`

All major browsers support this rule, see: https://caniuse.com/?search=text-transform

If you need to do this dynamically, the style can be set using JS.

The following snippet demonstrates both static and dynamic styling using css:

```js
function change() {
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].style="text-transform: capitalize;";
}
```

```css
p.styled {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p class="styled">i am using stack overflow and it is great</p>
<p>i am using stack overflow and it is great</p>

<button onclick="change()">capitalise</button>
```